# Displaying images in axes in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am rotating an image based on a condition and displaying it in a axes but it is not displaying rotated image.
here is code.

```
    if(a== 1.000000)
    r=imrotate(I,90);
   axes(handles.axes1);
   imshow(r);

   elseif(a==0.000000)
    r=imrotate(I,45);
   axes(handles.axes1);
   imshow(r);
```

Comment: This could be an issue with the image reference. Are you sure that `imrotate` is executing completely? I am assuming this is being done in a GUI because of the `handles` portion

Comment: dont use floating point numbers with logic... http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Where does `a` come from?  I hope you are not doing floating point computations to get it.  (See natan's comment.)